# Split an array into several arrays by defined boundaries, python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, split

I have a numpy array which consists of 64 columns and 49 rows. Each row stands for a separate message and contains several pieces of information. When an information starts or ends can be recognized by the change of the value. In the following an excerpt of the numpy array:

```
[[1 1 0 0 2 2 2 2 1 0 0 0 0 2 ... 2 2 2]
 [0 0 0 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 ... 2 2 2]
 [2 0 0 1 2 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ... 1 1 0]
 .
 .
 .
 [0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 ... 2 2 2]]
```

The first information of the first signal therefore takes the first two positions [11]. By changing the value from 1 to 0 I know that the second information is in the third and fourth position [00]. The third information occupies the following four positions [2222]. The next information consists only of [1]. And so on...

Once I have identified the positions of each information of a signal I have to apply these boundaries to my signal numpy arrays. My first binary signal numpy array consists of 64 columns and 3031 rows:

```
[[1 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 ... 1 0 0 1]
 [1 0 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 1 1 0 ... 1 1 1 0]
 [0 1 0 1 1 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 1 1 ... 1 1 1 0]
 .
 .
 .
 [1 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 1 ... 1 1 1 0]]
```

My first array (first information from the first signal) consists of the first two positions as determined by the previous array. The output should look like this:

```
[[11]
 [10]
 [01]
 .
 .
 .
 [10]]
```

The output of the second array (third and fourth position) should be the following:

```
[[00]
 [10]
 [01]
 .
 .
 .
 [10]]
```

The output of the third array:

```
[[0001]
 [1111]
 [1100]
 .
 .
 .
 [0100]]
```

Unfortunately I do not know how to create and apply the initial boundaries of the first array to the binary arrays. Does anyone have a solution for this?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, I placed the hint of where you should create a loop at the wrong place. See if this code works: (I tried to explain numpy slicing a little in comments but can learn more here: [Numpy indexing and slicing](https://www.pythoninformer.com/python-libraries/numpy/index-and-slice/)

```
import itertools
import numpy as np

# Def to reshape signals according to message
def reshape(lst1, lst2):
    iterator = iter(lst2)
    return [[next(iterator) for _ in sublist]
                         for sublist in lst1]

# Arrays
array_1 = np.array([[1,1,0,0,2,2,2,2,1,0,0,0,0,2],
                    [0,0,0,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2],
                    [2,0,0,1,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
                    [0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0]])

array_2 = np.array([[1,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0],
                    [1,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,0],
                    [0,1,0,1,1,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,1,1],
                    [1,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,1]])

#Group messages into pieces of information
signal_list = []
for lists in array_1:
    signal_list.append([list(group) for key, group in itertools.groupby(lists)])

#Index for all message
All_messages={}

#Do this for each message:
for rows in range(len(array_1)):
    #Reshapes each signal according to current message 
    signals_reshape = (np.array([reshape(signal_list[rows], array_2[i]) for i in range(len(array_2))]))

    # Create list to append all signals in current message
    all_signal = []
    # Do this for each information block
    for i in range(len(signals_reshape[rows])):
        '''
        Append information blocks 
        1st [:] = retrieve in all signals
        2nd [:] = retrieve the whole signal
        3rd [:,i] = retrieve information block from specific column
        Example: signals_reshape[0][0][0] retrieves the first information element of first information block of the fisrt signal
                 signals_reshape[0][0][:] retrieves all the information elements from the first information block from the first signal
                 signals_reshape[:][:][:,0] retrieves the first information block from all the signals
        '''
        all_signal.append(signals_reshape[:][:][:,i].flatten())     
    # add message information to dictionary (+ 1 is so that the names starts at Message1 and not Message0
    All_messages["Message{0}".format(rows+1)] = all_signal

print(All_messages['Message1'])
print(All_messages['Message2'])
print(All_messages['Message3'])
print(All_messages['Message4'])
```

Comment: Thank you for your trouble. Unfortunately I still received the index error. After some time I got it under control, but then the dictionary and other things did not work. I got 49 keys which was correct. Within each key all values (signals) of the 49 messages were stored. So I had 49 times the same. Finally I helped myself with a list (signals_reshape_list.append(signals_reshape) after generating signals_reshape in the for loop. With the help of signals_reshape_list[message][:,number_of_signal] I can access the values. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

See if this can help you. This example returns the information for the 1st message, but you should be able to create a loop for all 49 messages and assign it to a new list.

```
import itertools
import numpy as np

# Def to reshape signals according to message
def reshape(lst1, lst2):
    iterator = iter(lst2)
    return [[next(iterator) for _ in sublist]
                         for sublist in lst1]

# Arrays
array_1 = np.array([[1,1,0,0,2,2,2,2,1,0,0,0,0,2],
                    [0,0,0,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2],
                    [2,0,0,1,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]])

array_2 = np.array([[1,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0],
                    [1,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,0],
                    [0,1,0,1,1,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,1,1]])

#Group messages into pieces of information
signal_list = []
for lists in array_1:
    signal_list.append([list(group) for key, group in itertools.groupby(lists)])

# reshapes signals for each message to be used
signals_reshape = np.array([reshape(signal_list[0], array_2[i]) for i in range(len(array_2))])
print(signals_reshape[0])

# Get information from first message (Can create a loop to do the same for all 49 messages)
final_list_1 = []
for i in range(len(signals_reshape[0])):
    final_list_1.append(signals_reshape[:][:][:,i].flatten())

print(final_list_1[0])
print(final_list_1[1])
print(final_list_1[2])
```

## Output:

**final_list_1[0]**

[list([1, 1]), list([1, 0]), list([0, 1])]

**final_list_1[1]**

[list([0, 0]), list([1, 0]), list([0, 1])]

**final_list_1[2]**

[list([0, 0, 0, 1]) list([1, 1, 1, 1]) list([1, 1, 0, 0])]

Comment: Many thanks for the fast help! This is exactly what I was looking for. Especially the comments were very helpful for my understanding. In the beginning I made the mistake to take only the first line of the first array, which caused the error " 'numpy.uint8' object is not iterable". Then I helped myself with the function reshape(8,8). As a result, only the first line consisting of 8 bits was processed. In the meantime I use the whole array and it works fine. Thanks a lot!

Comment: It's a pleasure. I'm also in my early stages of python so I'm sure there will be a better way, especially with all the loops but I'm glad if it works in the meantime.

Comment: Today I tried to write a loop to extract all information of the 49 messages at once. Except the last two messages (message 48 and message 49) it works. The problem seems to be that the index of the messages is higher than the number of lines in which data is stored. The index of message 48 is "47", but there are only two lines of data with 64 bits each. I get the error: IndexError: index 47 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 2. Do you know what it could be? Can you explain to me what the three square brackets in the last line stand for?

Comment: Seems like I can't update my answer, so I posted a new one. Hope that works on all your data

Answer (score 0):

Credits to @Kempie. He has solved the problem. I just adapted his code to my needs, shortened it a bit and fixed some small bugs.

```
 import itertools
 import numpy as np

# Def to reshape signals according to message
def reshape(lst1, lst2):
    iterator = iter(lst2)
    return [[next(iterator) for _ in sublist]
                         for sublist in lst1]

# Arrays
array_1 = np.array([[1,1,0,0,2,2,2,2,1,0,0,0,0,2],
                    [0,0,0,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2],
                    [2,0,0,1,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
                    [0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0]])

#in my case, array_2 was a list (see difference of code to Kempies solutions)
array_2 = np.array([[1,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0],
                    [1,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,0],
                    [0,1,0,1,1,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,1,1],
                    [1,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,1]])

#Group messages into pieces of information
signal_list = []
for lists in array_1:
    signal_list.append([list(group) for key, group in itertools.groupby(lists)])

signals_reshape_list = []
#Do this for each message (as array_2 is a list, we must work with indices):
for rows in range(len(array_1)):
    #Reshapes each signal according to current message 
    signals_reshape = (np.array([reshape(signal_list[rows], array_2[rows][i]) for i in range(len(array_2[rows]))]))
    signals_reshape_list.append(signals_reshape)

#print first signal of third message e.g.
print(signals_reshape_list[2][:,0]
```